# File upload security Concern

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, file-upload

I am having a web form available to public, which has file upload capability. Now files are either saved on web server or sent out as attachment in an email.  We are having restriction on size i.e 15MB and extensions of file being uploaded. Our SMTP server is on same web server. I have concern about security, as anyone can upload malicious files and can have impact on our production web server.

What are the risks I will be having by such file upload control available to public? Is there anyway someone can execute malicious script on web server by uploading malicious file.

I did some research and found out following points

1. If I sent out a file as an attachment in an email, this file will be stored for temporary period in Temporary ASP .Net folders, and once email is sent this will get deleted.
2. You can rename a file before saving them on file system.
3. You can save file on different location as your website
4. You can have some sort of real time virus check. I am not sure how you can do that. I was reading about some command line virus scan. But not sure if I really need that.

These are just few points, but I would like to know about any blind spots in file upload.

Comment: Actually, if you send it as an attachment, it never touches your disk.

Comment: I'm not even going to try to answer, I usually get down votes for not suggesting something airtight. Airtight is not having any features. That said, if you put an invalid web.config or otherwise malformed web.config into the upload folder, you can prevent any .net code from executing. You'd want to make sure that you are blocking all extension that map to something that executes on your server, including .php, .axd, .ashx and so on.

Comment: Be careful your form doesn't become a spammers favorite toy. Limit how many people it can be sent to and how often, in addition to defending the file risks.

Comment: @SLaks: I was reading about somewhere that, it depends on your requestLengthDiskThreshold setting of httpruntime. It may buffer the file into asp .net temporary folders if your file size is more than requestLengthDiskThreshold. Also, your attachment can ended in one of the mailroot folder inside inetpub for any kid of smtp related errors.

Answer (score 8):

To answer your question about possible security vulnerabilities, yes you can definately create vulnerabilities in your application and for your users even if you don't save the file to the disk.  But there are a few lines of defense you can take to validate.

The first is to obviously restrict the types of files that can be uploaded, you can do this with a **white list** and a check of the extension **but don't stop there.**  You should also verify by looking at the contents of the file to ensure that it complies with the expected format.  This can be critical as a bad guy can inject file headers into the file uploaded and use your system as a zombie for passing around his malware.

Second you should run a virus scan against the uploaded file, you can do this by using a command line to execute a local virus scanner.  This is an easy thing to do with many virus scans including Trend Micro, and unless you're looking at a massive amount of file uploads then it should not be a huge tax on your server.

Ensure that you **never pass paths** as user submitted data (via GET or POST to download) as that can expose you to a path traversal attack.  If your user needs to download the file from the browser you can create a database of where the records are stored and then create a controller or page that will fetch it based on the database record and the users access to that record, rather than provide a path which a user can control and use to get files from your server.

Ensure that the directory you will save to is **not readable by the web server**, this way they don't upload a malware script and then execute it from their browser via an HTTP

Ensure that you validate all user input against some anti-XSS library (Microsoft provides one http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to upload them to /App_Data folder or to store them in a database as binary objects. App_Data is not readable through the web server, so this will protect you against execute and script access. An alternative to storing them in binary is to Base 64 encode them and store them in text (again either in the file system App_Data or database).

Create a proxy page to check the user has permissions to view/download the file and if so send a stream of the file to the HTTP response. This way users do not have direct access and cannot execute anything they shouldn't. You can also attach files using the SMTP classes from a stream reference.

If storing in the file system you could implement your own naming convention so that a request for the actual file is mapped to the stored version.

Virus scanning can be useful, but think of this as protecting other users that may have access to download the file rather than protecting your server.